# Intent arguments at run time

Tags: java, android, android-intent, types

While working with some android code, I came across a doubt(may be dumb) but I want to clear it...

---

**I was trying:** to start a splash screen everytime in  an application which will read some sharedpreferences too, and according to that value of that sharedpreference the next activity will be opened.

---

**I got stuck:** When I was unable to figure out that what to pass as arguments to the intent(see the only comment in the code)

```
if(appStatus==0)
{
    activityToOpen="LoginActivity";
}
else if(appStatus==1)
{
    activityToOpen="SecondActivity";
}

int secondsDelayed = 1;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            Intent i=new Intent(MainSplashScreen.this,);//here how should be the second argument will be added
            startActivity(i);
                    finish();
            }
    }, secondsDelayed * 1000);
```

type of `activityToOpen` is `String`.I don't know what type of variable it is,the `.class`

Comment: new Intent(MainSplashScreen.this,LoginActivity.class); 1 param fromwhere 2 is to where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use generic class as

```
Class<?> cls = null;

if(appStatus==0)
{
     cls = LoginActivity.class;
}
else if(appStatus==1)
{
    cls = SecondActivity.class;
}
```

And pass `cls` parameter as

```
Intent i=new Intent(MainSplashScreen.this,cls);
```

Comment: @DividebyZero Happy to help,enjoy coding.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do this with an `if statement` and use your `appStatus` to check if you want to go the  `LoginActivity` or `SecondActivity` and instantiate your `Intent` constructor depending on the token.

**sample:**

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        Intent i;
        if(appStatus==0)
           i=new Intent(MainSplashScreen.this,LoginActivity.class);
        else if(appStatus==1)
           i=new Intent(MainSplashScreen.this,SecondActivity.class);

        startActivity(i);
                finish();
        }
}, secondsDelayed * 1000);
```

Comment: yeay,it will work.but Is there no way out to  set value of some variable and pass it as second argument to intent?

Comment: upvoted,but @Giru Bhai answer is what i was looking for

Comment: @DividebyZero I mean upvote the answer that answered your question

Answer (score 2):

Use or above if else below like this:...........

```
Intent i;
if(appStatus==0)
{
   i = new Intent(this,LoginActivity.class);
}
else if(appStatus==1)
{
     i = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
}
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

You make instance of the class using for loop and pass it as second argument.

**For example:**

Make a static field in each as `public static Activity activity = this;`
And then get it and pass the object as second parameter

Of course you will need to get the activity using `condition`